# stringified string with special character and space as data attribute jquery

Tags: jquery, string, attributes

i have a string from php that looks like below

> [{"lngID":"1","strRefTable":"team","strRefValue":"Automation","strLongDesc":"Automation","strShortDesc":"Auto boys'","bitActive":1}]

String has a space and a `'`

I want to append it to an object as data attribute i tried

```
objdata.push("<button class='btn btn-info user_action' data-action='edit' id='btnUpdateModal' data-obj='" + JSON.stringify(v) + "'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit</button>")
```

and

```
objdata.push('<button class="btn btn-info user_action" data-action="edit" id="btnUpdateModal" data-obj=' + JSON.stringify(v) + '><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>')
```

but but does not return the entire string as data value both of them cuts the string in the `'` or in the `{`

Any idea how to correctly append the string as data attribute

```js
var data = [{
  "lngID": "1",
  "strRefTable": "team",
  "strRefValue": "Automation",
  "strLongDesc": "Automation",
  "strShortDesc": "Auto boys'",
  "bitActive": 1
}];
$('div').append('<button class="btn btn-info user_action" data-action="edit" id="btnUpdateModal" data-obj=' + JSON.stringify(data) + '><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>')
$('div').append("<button class='btn btn-info user_action' data-action='edit' id='btnUpdateModal' data-obj='" + JSON.stringify(data) + "'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit</button>")

$("div").on('click', 'button', function() {

  console.log(JSON.parse($(this).attr("data-obj")))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON object contains a another apostrophe on attribute `'strShortDesc'` value `"Auto boys'"`. Remove the character and it will works fine.